# I am getting the error: 'docker: invalid reference format'

Tags: docker, powershell

This is my command:

```
docker run --name online-exam-db \
    -p 5432:5432 \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=online-exam \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=0NLIN3-ex4m \
    -d postgres
```

I have researched a lot and I am not finding a solution. I am doing the following tutorial where I also got the command from: https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/

I appreciate your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker run --name online-exam-db -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=online-exam -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=0NLIN3-ex4m -d postgres`

trying running the command in a single line, im guessing you ran this command on command prompt and just copy pasted it in.

so what happened was that it was trying to run `docker run --name online-exam-db \`  which docker wont recognize the `\`

Answer (score 0):

The command you got from tutorial is for macos, while you are working on windows powershell.

To continue a command on the next line, different interactive prompt will use different symbol:

| Linux Shell | OSX Terminal | Windows Dos | Windows Powershell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \ | \ | ^ | ` |

So, if you insist to write your command with multiple lines in powershell, you should use backquote(`):

```
docker run --name online-exam-db `
    -p 5432:5432 `
    -e POSTGRES_DB=online-exam `
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=0NLIN3-ex4m `
    -d postgres
```